sharing a link via email and whatsapp
below is the function that I created to copy a link, send it via whatsapp and send it via email but it's showing just simple text on the email and whatsapp what am I missing here?
const handleShareOption = async (option: 'copy' | 'email' | 'whatsapp') => {
    try {
      const externalUrl = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/report/view/${report.reportExternalId}`;
      const message = `Confira este relatório: ${externalUrl}`;
      const subject = 'Compartilhar Relatório';

      const whatsappLink = `https://wa.me/?text=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`;
      const mailtoLink = `mailto:?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`;

      switch (option) {
        case 'copy':
          if (navigator.clipboard) {
            try {
              await navigator.clipboard.writeText(externalUrl);
              toast.success('Link compartilhável copiado!');
            } catch (error) {
              toast.error('Não foi possível copiar o link. Tente novamente.');
            }
          } else {
            // Fallback for browsers without clipboard API
            try {
              const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
              textArea.value = externalUrl;
              document.body.appendChild(textArea);
              textArea.select();
              document.execCommand('copy');
              document.body.removeChild(textArea);
              toast.success('Link copiado com sucesso!');
            } catch (error) {
              toast.error(
                'Seu navegador não suporta copiar para área de transferência.'
              );
            }
          }
          break;

        case 'email':
          try {
            window.open(mailtoLink, '_blank');
          } catch (error) {
            toast.error('Não foi possível abrir o cliente de email.');
          }
          break;

        case 'whatsapp':
          try {
            window.open(whatsappLink, '_blank');
          } catch (error) {
            toast.error('Não foi possível abrir o WhatsApp.');
          }
          break;

        default:
          throw new Error('Opção inválida');
      }

      handleMenuClose(); // Close the menu after selecting an option
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar compartilhar. Tente novamente.');
      console.error(error); // Log the error for debugging purposes
    }
  };

So I'm making this so the user can share the link for its report but its only being send as a plain text and I want it to be a clickable link
